# Java Servlet retrieve Spring RequestMapping Url

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I wrote a Request Interceptor to add some Information to Requests in Test-Environment.

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
    ...
}

public void postHandle(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {
        ...
}
```

Currently I'm retrieving the URLs like this:

```
String url = request.getServletPath();
```

For a Controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getByID(@PathVariable long ID) {
    ...
}
```

And for a Request like `/1/`
`url` would be `/1/`

Is there any way to get the Request-Mapping-Value ==> `/{id}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: id is a path variable so if you request /1 in url would be /1 and 1 ->id . change "/{id}" to  "/{id}*" for accepting /1, /1/

Comment: inside the interceptor i want to retriev /{id}/ as String i dont care about the id itself (1)

Comment: Inside preHandle use request.getRequestURL().toString() or equest.getQueryString() to retriev /{id}/ as string

Comment: getRequestURL returns the full link localhost:8080/1, querystring is null but i want /{id}

Comment: you can't achieve this because /{id} you have define in controller for path variable. Interceptor intercept what ever you pass in url like you pass /1 so how it will map with {id}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestMapping` and its composed annotation methods (i.e. `@GetMapping` , `@PostMapping` etc.) are handled by `HandlerMethod`. So cast the handler object to it and you can access the `@RequestMapping` information that you want:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        HandlerMethod hm = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        RequestMapping mapping = hm.getMethodAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
        if (mapping != null) {
            for(String val : mapping.value()) {

                //***This is the mapping value of @RequestMapping***
                System.out.println(val);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```